# How to get information out of Wireshark

Tags: networking, internet, wireshark

I need to make a program that makes use of information that Wireshark collects from the network. Is there a way to get that information from Wireshark and into the program?

Comment: The log files perhaps? strange that you haven't mentioned trying it

Comment: Standard log files on just about any OS doesn't provide low level information about the network, especially at the packet level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) on Windows or [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/) on Linux.

Comment: What about for OSX?

Comment: @OSXJedi: Also `tcpdump`. :)